# Which block explorer indexes the keys used in mutisig scripts?

Tags: multi-signature, blockexplorer

Consider transaction [`0846e91bc3afdf2275db14bcbb10e19f141069d77f17dae6bcbd907fd28f4747`](https://blockchain.info/tx/0846e91bc3afdf2275db14bcbb10e19f141069d77f17dae6bcbd907fd28f4747), which takes money out of the script address `3PJQGGnBQr8DJBdPYowd6Mp2kSWvFFo7Gk`. As we can see in the input scripts, this script address references script `51210261afd7a2796e9bb83896089293f11edd2987ebbd67ed2075f5e45b7c4bb7edcb51ae`, which, according to the [`decodescript`](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/decodescript) command, is

```
    "asm": "1 0261afd7a2796e9bb83896089293f11edd2987ebbd67ed2075f5e45b7c4bb7edcb 1 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
    "reqSigs": 1,
    "type": "multisig",
    "addresses": [
        "1xW3APNVG6Ro1HY8hysmnKq8mvgVk6oPU"
    ],
    "p2sh": "3PJQGGnBQr8DJBdPYowd6Mp2kSWvFFo7Gk"
```

So this payment was made to anyone who has access to the key with the address `1xW3APNVG6Ro1HY8hysmnKq8mvgVk6oPU`.

But none of the common block explorer websites seem to index this; when I [ask them about the address `1xW3APNVG6Ro1HY8hysmnKq8mvgVk6oPU`](https://blockexplorer.com/address/1xW3APNVG6Ro1HY8hysmnKq8mvgVk6oPU), they list no transactions.

Is there a block explorer that maintains a mapping from key address to the script addresses the key is mentioned in?

Answer (score 1):

You must not see the address in the blockchain as a receiving address. It is a P2SH tx, which means, that the spending condition is sha256’d. This is the type 3address above. The 1-of-1 multisig condition inside defines, that anyone who has the private key to the “1xW3APN...” address can spend this tx, which happened on 2014-07-28 to the target address “1UxOYSY...” 
I highly recommend reading Andreas’ book mastering bitcoin (online available), which explains in nice detail the reasons and insights of those multisig adddresses.

Blockexplorer blockchain.info obviously doesn’t show the decoded script, cause it is not an address used to receive funds.

Comment: I understand that. But still, when I want to find “everything on the blockchain related to ” `1xW3APN`, can’t I reasonably expect to be shown the 3address above? (Of course only once that address has been used once, so that the actual script is publicly known)

Comment: I see, then maybe this: https://webbtc.com/script/0846e91bc3afdf2275db14bcbb10e19f141069d77f17dae6bcbd907fd28f4747:0 - it would decode the "Inner P2SH Script" ...

Comment: That’s a cool resource, thanks! It even turns `1xW3APNVG6Ro1HY8hysmnKq8mvgVk6oPU` into [a link](https://webbtc.com/address/1xW3APNVG6Ro1HY8hysmnKq8mvgVk6oPU). But then there is no back link.

Obviously the data is there, and it _could_ link back to that transaction, but it seems that is not done. I guess nobody else wanted this before :-)

Answer (score 0):

On blockchain.info you can look it up by [3PJQGGnBQr8DJBdPYowd6Mp2kSWvFFo7Gk](https://blockchain.info/address/3PJQGGnBQr8DJBdPYowd6Mp2kSWvFFo7Gk) which is the keyed address that was used (p2sh).